# How do you return a list of the matched item in string with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I made this simple functions that searches for emails in the source code of a page , the content is just the response taken from get request , now how do you return the matchs in `findall` as a list with out the `\n` or ant other unwanted strings

My goal is to get a list of all the matched strings (emails)

```
def find_emails(content):
    email_reg =  r"""[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.+[a-zA-Z0-9]*"""
    mail_lst = re.findall(email_reg , content)
    return mail_lst
```

when the program reaches this for loop i get the emails found in the regex but they are separated by `\n` and i get some random string in between the emails

I tried using brackets in my regex but this didn't make any difference

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = find_emails(content)
    for item in res:
        print(item)
```

Comment: Dot `.` is a regex _metacharacter_, and needs to be escaped as `\.`

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
```

your regex is wrong , . matches all occurance

```
def find_emails(content):
    email_reg =  r"^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$"
    mail_lst = re.findall(email_reg , content)
    return mail_lst

print(find_emails("hiiii@asdasd.££$%%$com"))
print(find_emails("hiiii@asdasd.asdasd.com"))
```